# $digest error when calling $apply after a $compile

Tags: angularjs

I am building a directive to handle rollover tooltips.  I've integrated HoverIntent with Zurb Foundations Tooltip class.  It works! **However**... I get the dreaded `Error: $digest already in progress` error that we're all too familiar with.  This only occurs the very first time the `buildFromTemplate` function gets executed.  Ideally I'd like to remove the `scope.$apply()` from my code, however I'm not sure how i can do that while maintaining proper functionality.

**Usage Types:** *There are three different ways to use this directive, yet the issue only happens on Usage 3*

```
# Usage 1:
%a(rollover title="Add New")

# Usage 2:
%a(rollover rollover-element"#some-element-id")
%div(id="some-element-id")
  Add New

# Usage 3:
%a(rollover rollover-template="rollover1.html")
# FILE 'rollover1.html':
%div
  {{data.name}}
```

**The Code (in coffee script):**

```
angular.module('app.common').directive 'rollover', ['$http', '$compile', '$templateCache', ($http, $compile, $templateCache) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  scope: true
  replace: false
  template: ''

  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    selector = ''

    buildFromTemplate = (html) ->
      compiled = $compile( angular.element("<div>"+html+"</div>") )(scope)

      # ERROR Occurs Here:
      scope.$apply()

      # Without the scope.$apply, compiled.html() still contains unparsed {{variables}}
      element.attr('title', compiled.html())
      selector = 'tooltip' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
      element.attr('data-tooltip','').attr('data-selector',selector).trigger('mouseenter')

    showOrCreate = ->
      # Build Appropriately
      if selector == '' and typeof attrs.rolloverTemplate == "string" and attrs.rolloverTemplate != ""
        template = $templateCache.get(attrs.rolloverTemplate)
        if !template
          $http.get(attrs.rolloverTemplate, {cache: $templateCache}).then (content) ->
            $templateCache.put(attrs.rolloverTemplate, content.data)
            buildFromTemplate(content.data)
        else
          buildFromTemplate(template)
      else
        if selector == ''
          if typeof attrs.rolloverElement == "string" and attrs.rolloverElement != ""
            element.attr('title', $(attrs.rolloverElement).html())
          selector = 'tooltip' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)

        element.attr('data-tooltip','').attr('data-selector',selector).trigger('mouseenter')

    hide = ->
      element.removeAttr('data-tooltip','').removeAttr('data-selector')
      $(".tooltip[data-selector="+selector+"]").hide()

    element.hoverIntent
      over: showOrCreate
      out: hide
      interval: 250
]
```

Any help / ideas are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular's [`$interpolate` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate) to do the *interpolation* if that is the only reason you are using `scope.$apply` in the `buildFromTemplate`.

```coffeescript
angular.module('app.common').directive 'rollover', ['$http', '$compile', '$templateCache', '$interpolate', ($http, $compile, $templateCache, $interpolate) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  scope: true
  replace: false
  template: ''

  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    selector = ''

    buildFromTemplate = (html) ->
      compiled = $interpolate(html)(scope)

      element.attr('title', compiled)
      selector = 'tooltip' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
      element.attr('data-tooltip','').attr('data-selector',selector).trigger('mouseenter')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I updated the answer  a little bit with the updated code that worked for me.

Comment: I have made the changes.